# Como executar uma ação ao responder um email

Tags: facebook, email

Em alguns sistema eu vejo uma funcionalidade bem interessante, como por exemplo:

Eu recebo uma mensagem no [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) e o ele me envia um e-mail com a mensagem, e posso responder a mensagem simplesmente respondendo o e-mail.

Como funciona isso? O que preciso pesquisar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O segredo está na linha de assunto ou no endereço de email usado para o envio, que contém um token que serve para identificar a mensagem.

Para implementar tal tipo de funcionalidade por sua conta, você precisa dominar vários assuntos, entre eles:

- geração e armazenamento de tokens em DB, ou algum sistema de armazenagem;
- envio de email pelo seu sistema;
- receber um email programaticamente no seu sistema, ou implementação de um servidor SMTP;
- processamento deste email para retirar a informação desejada, identificar o token correto e fazer a reinserçao no seu sistema.

Claro que isso é só um ponto de partida.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Bacco, ajudou bastante :)